unable to generate multiple-cucumber-html-report from json output file of @wdio/json-reporter
I am trying to set up a typescript with webdriver IO and cucumber framework project from scratch .
Below is the content of my package.json
{"name": "typescript_wdio_cucumber","version": "1.0.0","description": "Typescript with WDIO and Cucumber","main": "index.js","scripts": {"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1","wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.ts","generate-report": "ts-node ./generate-report.ts",},"author": "NishashreeJC","license": "ISC","devDependencies": {"@types/node": "^22.5.3","@wdio/cli": "^9.0.7","@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^9.0.6","@wdio/json-reporter": "^9.0.8","@wdio/local-runner": "^9.0.7","@wdio/spec-reporter": "^9.0.7","multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^3.7.0","ts-node": "^10.9.2","typescript": "^5.5.4","wdio-wait-for": "^3.0.11"}}

And below is the content of my wdio.conf.ts file
import type { Options } from '@wdio/types'
export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
//// ====================// Runner Configuration// ====================// WebdriverIO supports running e2e tests as well as unit and component tests.runner: 'local',tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',  
// // ================== // Specify Test Files // ================== // Define which test specs should run. The pattern is relative to the directory // of the configuration file being run. // // The specs are defined as an array of spec files (optionally using wildcards // that will be expanded). The test for each spec file will be run in a separate // worker process. In order to have a group of spec files run in the same worker // process simply enclose them in an array within the specs array. // // The path of the spec files will be resolved relative from the directory of // of the config file unless it's absolute. // specs: [     './features/**/*.feature' ], // Patterns to exclude. exclude: [     // 'path/to/excluded/files' ], // // ============ // Capabilities // ============ // Define your capabilities here. WebdriverIO can run multiple capabilities at the same // time. Depending on the number of capabilities, WebdriverIO launches several test // sessions. Within your capabilities you can overwrite the spec and exclude options in // order to group specific specs to a specific capability. // // First, you can define how many instances should be started at the same time. Let's // say you have 3 different capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) and you have // set maxInstances to 1; wdio will spawn 3 processes. Therefore, if you have 10 spec // files and you set maxInstances to 10, all spec files will get tested at the same time // and 30 processes will get spawned. The property handles how many capabilities // from the same test should run tests. // maxInstances: 10, // // If you have trouble getting all important capabilities together, check out the // Sauce Labs platform configurator - a great tool to configure your capabilities: // https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator // capabilities: [{     browserName: 'chrome' }],  // // =================== // Test Configurations // =================== // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here // // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent logLevel: 'info', // // Set specific log levels per logger // loggers: // - webdriver, webdriverio // - @wdio/browserstack-service, @wdio/lighthouse-service, @wdio/sauce-service // - @wdio/mocha-framework, @wdio/jasmine-framework // - @wdio/local-runner // - @wdio/sumologic-reporter // - @wdio/cli, @wdio/config, @wdio/utils // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent // logLevels: { //     webdriver: 'info', //     '@wdio/appium-service': 'info' // }, // // If you only want to run your tests until a specific amount of tests have failed use // bail (default is 0 - don't bail, run all tests). bail: 0, // // Set a base URL in order to shorten url command calls. If your `url` parameter starts // with `/`, the base url gets prepended, not including the path portion of your baseUrl. // If your `url` parameter starts without a scheme or `/` (like `some/path`), the base url // gets prepended directly. // baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080', // // Default timeout for all waitFor* commands. waitforTimeout: 10000, // // Default timeout in milliseconds for request // if browser driver or grid doesn't send response connectionRetryTimeout: 120000, // // Default request retries count connectionRetryCount: 3, // // Test runner services // Services take over a specific job you don't want to take care of. They enhance // your test setup with almost no effort. Unlike plugins, they don't add new // commands. Instead, they hook themselves up into the test process. // services: [], // // Framework you want to run your specs with. // The following are supported: Mocha, Jasmine, and Cucumber // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/frameworks // // Make sure you have the wdio adapter package for the specific framework installed // before running any tests. framework: 'cucumber',  // // The number of times to retry the entire specfile when it fails as a whole // specFileRetries: 1, // // Delay in seconds between the spec file retry attempts // specFileRetriesDelay: 0, // // Whether or not retried spec files should be retried immediately or deferred to the end of the queue // specFileRetriesDeferred: false, // // Test reporter for stdout. // The only one supported by default is 'dot' // see also: https://webdriver.io/docs/dot-reporter // reporters: ['spec'],  reporters: [     'spec',     ['json',{         outputDir: './results'     }]         ],  // If you are using Cucumber you need to specify the location of your step definitions. cucumberOpts: {     // <string[]> (file/dir) require files before executing features     require: ['./features/step-definitions/steps.ts'],     // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors     backtrace: false,     // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)     requireModule: [],     // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps     dryRun: false,     // <boolean> abort the run on first failure     failFast: false,     // <string[]> Only execute the scenarios with name matching the expression (repeatable).     name: [],     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps     snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide source uris     source: true,     // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps     strict: false,     // <string> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression     tagExpression: '',     // <number> timeout for step definitions     timeout: 60000,     // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.     ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false },   // // ===== // Hooks // ===== // WebdriverIO provides several hooks you can use to interfere with the test process in order to enhance // it and to build services around it. You can either apply a single function or an array of // methods to it. If one of them returns with a promise, WebdriverIO will wait until that promise got // resolved to continue. /**  * Gets executed once before all workers get launched.  * @param {object} config wdio configuration object  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  */ // onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) { // }, /**  * Gets executed before a worker process is spawned and can be used to initialize specific service  * for that worker as well as modify runtime environments in an async fashion.  * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)  * @param  {object} caps     object containing capabilities for session that will be spawn in the worker  * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process  * @param  {object} args     object that will be merged with the main configuration once worker is initialized  * @param  {object} execArgv list of string arguments passed to the worker process  */ // onWorkerStart: function (cid, caps, specs, args, execArgv) { // }, /**  * Gets executed just after a worker process has exited.  * @param  {string} cid      capability id (e.g 0-0)  * @param  {number} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail  * @param  {object} specs    specs to be run in the worker process  * @param  {number} retries  number of retries used  */ // onWorkerEnd: function (cid, exitCode, specs, retries) { // }, /**  * Gets executed just before initialising the webdriver session and test framework. It allows you  * to manipulate configurations depending on the capability or spec.  * @param {object} config wdio configuration object  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run  * @param {string} cid worker id (e.g. 0-0)  */ // beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs, cid) { // }, /**  * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global  * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  * @param {Array.<String>} specs        List of spec file paths that are to be run  * @param {object}         browser      instance of created browser/device session  */ // before: function (capabilities, specs) { // }, /**  * Runs before a WebdriverIO command gets executed.  * @param {string} commandName hook command name  * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive  */ // beforeCommand: function (commandName, args) { // }, /**  * Cucumber Hooks  *  * Runs before a Cucumber Feature.  * @param {string}                   uri      path to feature file  * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object  */ // beforeFeature: function (uri, feature) { // }, /**  *  * Runs before a Cucumber Scenario.  * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world    world object containing information on pickle and test step  * @param {object}                 context  Cucumber World object  */ // beforeScenario: function (world, context) { // }, /**  *  * Runs before a Cucumber Step.  * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step     step data  * @param {IPickle}            scenario scenario pickle  * @param {object}             context  Cucumber World object  */ // beforeStep: function (step, scenario, context) { // }, /**  *  * Runs after a Cucumber Step.  * @param {Pickle.IPickleStep} step             step data  * @param {IPickle}            scenario         scenario pickle  * @param {object}             result           results object containing scenario results  * @param {boolean}            result.passed    true if scenario has passed  * @param {string}             result.error     error stack if scenario failed  * @param {number}             result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds  * @param {object}             context          Cucumber World object  */ // afterStep: function (step, scenario, result, context) { // }, /**  *  * Runs after a Cucumber Scenario.  * @param {ITestCaseHookParameter} world            world object containing information on pickle and test step  * @param {object}                 result           results object containing scenario results  * @param {boolean}                result.passed    true if scenario has passed  * @param {string}                 result.error     error stack if scenario failed  * @param {number}                 result.duration  duration of scenario in milliseconds  * @param {object}                 context          Cucumber World object  */ // afterScenario: function (world, result, context) { // }, /**  *  * Runs after a Cucumber Feature.  * @param {string}                   uri      path to feature file  * @param {GherkinDocument.IFeature} feature  Cucumber feature object  */ // afterFeature: function (uri, feature) { // },  /**  * Runs after a WebdriverIO command gets executed  * @param {string} commandName hook command name  * @param {Array} args arguments that command would receive  * @param {number} result 0 - command success, 1 - command error  * @param {object} error error object if any  */ // afterCommand: function (commandName, args, result, error) { // }, /**  * Gets executed after all tests are done. You still have access to all global variables from  * the test.  * @param {number} result 0 - test pass, 1 - test fail  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran  */ // after: function (result, capabilities, specs) { // }, /**  * Gets executed right after terminating the webdriver session.  * @param {object} config wdio configuration object  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that ran  */ // afterSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) { // }, /**  * Gets executed after all workers got shut down and the process is about to exit. An error  * thrown in the onComplete hook will result in the test run failing.  * @param {object} exitCode 0 - success, 1 - fail  * @param {object} config wdio configuration object  * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details  * @param {<Object>} results object containing test results  */ // onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) { // }, /** * Gets executed when a refresh happens. * @param {string} oldSessionId session ID of the old session * @param {string} newSessionId session ID of the new session */ // onReload: function(oldSessionId, newSessionId) { // } /** * Hook that gets executed before a WebdriverIO assertion happens. * @param {object} params information about the assertion to be executed */ // beforeAssertion: function(params) { // } /** * Hook that gets executed after a WebdriverIO assertion happened. * @param {object} params information about the assertion that was executed, including its results */ // afterAssertion: function(params) { // }
}

below is the content of my generate-report.ts file
// @ts-ignoreimport { generate } from 'multiple-cucumber-html-reporter'; 

generate({jsonDir: './results', // Path to the directory containing JSON reportsreportPath: './reports/html/', // Path where the HTML report should be generatedmetadata: {browser: { name: 'chrome', version: '91' },device: 'Local Machine',platform: { name: 'windows', version: '10' }},customData: {title: 'Run info',data: [{ label: 'Project', value: 'My Project' },{ label: 'Release', value: '1.0.0' },{ label: 'Cycle', value: 'B11221.34321' },{ label: 'Execution Start Time', value: new Date().toLocaleString() },{ label: 'Execution End Time', value: new Date().toLocaleString() },]}});

while I try to generate the report getting the below error: as shown in screenshot .- looks like the json generated is not in the correct format or correct match as needed by multiple-cucumber-html-reporter to generate html from jsons . please help me on getting this issue solved
expecting to get a html report , with screenshots for failed test case step

json-reporter generates json in a format that will not be in cucumber format. hence for setting up "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter" - we need to install "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter" and "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter". official documents link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiple-cucumber-html-reporter and
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter
